# Compare two files according to first column and print whole line

Tags: awk

I will ask my question with an example. I have 2 files:

**File1-**

```
TR100013|c0_g1
TR100013|c0_g2
TR10009|c0_g1
TR10009|c0_g2
```

**File2-**

```
TR100013|c0_g1  AT1G01360.1 78.79   165 35  0   301 795 19  183 2E-089  272
TR100013|c0_g2  AT1G01360.1 78.79   165 35  0   301 795 19  183 2E-089  272
TR10009|c0_g1   AT1G16240.3 77.42   62  14  0   261 76  113 174 4E-025  95.9
TR10009|c0_g2   AT1G16240.2 69.17   120 37  0   1007    648 113 232 2E-050  171
TR29295|c0_g1   AT1G22540.1 69.19   172 53  2   6   521 34  200 2E-053  180
TR49005|c5_g1   AT5G24530.1 69.21   302 90  1   909 13  39  340 5E-157  446
```

**Expected Output :**

```
TR100013|c0_g1  AT1G01360.1 78.79   165 35  0   301 795 19  183 2E-089  272
TR100013|c0_g2  AT1G01360.1 78.79   165 35  0   301 795 19  183 2E-089  272
TR10009|c0_g1   AT1G16240.3 77.42   62  14  0   261 76  113 174 4E-025  95.9
TR10009|c0_g2   AT1G16240.2 69.17   120 37  0   1007    648 113 232 2E-050  171
```

I want to compare two files. If the first column is same in both files, then print the whole line of second file which is common in both files.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next};a[$1]' file1 file2
```

`grep` can do the same:

```
grep -wf file1 file2
```

`-w` is to match whole word only.
`-f` specifies the file with the pattern.

Comment: Why are you setting FS to | ?

Comment: I thought it's based on the field before `|` for some reason.

Comment: This command is not able to give any result. It gives nothing.

Comment: @amy It tested and it works as expected. You are not incorrectly giving file names? Does the `grep` solution works?

Comment: @BlueMoon Thanks, yes it's working. The fault was on my part.